# How can I add background music to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, background, drupal-7, background-music

I have a Drupal 7 website. I want to add background music with mute/unmute options. It is a company website so I dont want to put something so big or playlist etc... just want to add soft background music which will play automaticly and it shouldnt stop or restart when clicking to another page.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question on drupal.stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/how-can-i-add-background-music-to-an-existing-drupal-7-website) for some suggestions about doing this via ajax or a popunder window with a player. Background music on websites is widely considered to be very bad design, but if you have to do it, it looks possible.